# What are Selenium, JUnit, Ant and JScover and how they are combined?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, test-design, junit

I am given a javascript function which takes as input some numbers and returns the max, as a part of a project at the university, and I have to test it, using Selenium, JUnit, Ant and JScover. I have seen some tutorials about each one individually([ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html),[JUnit Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_quick_guide.htm),[Selenium tutorial](http://www.jroller.com/selenium/)) and I have understood that JScover just graphically presents you the results of the test.

However, I have difficulties understanding the difference between Selenium, JUnit and Ant. I also do not know how to start making test cases. I have eclipse installed, and I have the function, but how I am supposed to combine the three, and what I should do in each one?

Do you also know any example which uses those that can help me?

Comment: Look for Selenium tutorials in Java; most use JUnit, though they tend to use Maven instead of Ant. That can help with understanding how those two tools interact at least

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Selenium is a tool that remote-controls a browser.  You can use it to simulate a user interacting with a web site.

JUnit is a framework for writing Java unit tests.  It takes some of the grunt work out of organizing tests and generating reports.  You can express each test as a method on a class; typically, you have multiple tests per class.  JUnit will run the tests for you and report which tests passed and which failed.  If you need to write tests for a web site, you might use JUnit tests that call Selenium APIs.

Ant is a tool for building software.  You describe a project in an XML file, and then Ant will use that description to build the software for you.  For example, it might compile your Java source code into class files and then combine those class files with some HTML files and some Javascript files into a WAR file.

JScover is a tool for determining code coverage.  A code coverage tool can help you understand which parts of your code are getting exercised by your tests.

Answer (score 0):

**we can simplify junit and selenium comparision as follow** :--

- Junit is used majorly to test server side/backend/Custom API unit
  testing, for ex: you make use of junit apis along with java code to
  test your backend logic by writing small parameteriasied method to
  check your code logic. Junit is also used with Selenium to automate
  everything.

  ```
   +++++++++++++++ **Sample Junit test Case** +++++++++++++++++++
   import org.junit.Test;
   import static org.junit.Assert.*;
   public class jUnitTestCase{
       @Test
       public void testConcatenation() {
           MyUnit myUnit = new performConcatenation();
           String result = myUnit.concatenate("A", "B");
           assertEquals("AB", result);
       }
   }
   +++++++++++++++ **Sample Custom API to be unit tested** +++++++++++++++
   public class performConcatenation{
       public String concatenate(String A, String B){
           return A+B;
       }
   }
  ```
- Where as Selenium is a tool (.jar+exe) which you use and then write
  use case in terms of programming to invoke browser to automate UI
  testing.

+++++++++++++++ **Sample Selenium test Case** +++++++++++++++++++

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```

public class LinkedInLogin {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
          WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(); driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
          driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/login"); 
          System.out.println("linked in invoked..............");
          WebElement username=driver.findElement(By.id("username")); 
          WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.id("password")); 
          WebElement login=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Sign in']")); 
          username.sendKeys("yourEmail-or-id@gmail.com"); password.sendKeys("your inkedIn Password"); 
          login.click(); String actualUrl="https://www.linkedin.com/feed/"; 
}
```

}