# what is difference between selenium web driver and junit?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit

I am confused about selenium webdriver and junit that are they same? please explain difference between them.

Comment: This link is also useful to you. [https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/what-are-selenium-junit-ant-and-jscover-and-how-they-are-combined]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium WebDriver is a tool using which we can automate any web application. It can open a browser, launch a URL, write on a text box, click buttons, etc. In short, it can simulate user actions.

But in order to test something, we need to have a tool that can provide us methods to pass-fail a test case based on the different validations, organise the test cases, create test reports, etc. That's where a testing framework like JUnit or TestNG comes into the picture.

So, for "Automation Testing" Selenium will help in the 'automation' part and Junit will help in the 'Testing' part.

Answer (score 4):

**Selenium** is a tool that remote-controls a browser, You can use it to simulate a user interacting with a web site. for more info go through [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver)

**JUnit** is a unit testing framework for writing Java unit tests.for more info go through [Junit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit)